# wifi scan is not performed when calling wifi.startScan() outside the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm working on an application which loads a map ( as an image). I'm using a customized view to load the image. I have to perform a wifi scan and store the results whenever the user touches the map.

I have declared the wifi manager this way:

```
public static WifiManager wifi;
```

so that I can use it inside my customized view. When I call `wifi.startScan();` from the customized view it doesn't perform the scan. It runs without errors or exceptions but no scan result is available.

This is the code of my broadcast receiver:

```
   public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


        /*
         * This receiver will set a flag in the main activity to indicate the new scan result has been set
         * it will set the new result too.
         * 
         */
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            result=wifi.getScanResults();

            Log.d("surveyTool","scanning result set");


        }
        }
```

As far as understand how scanning work, whenever `wifi.startScan()` is called, the code inside `onReceiver()` should be executed when the scan result is available. But this is not happening.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?? or what should I do in order to start the scan from my customized view?

Note: I have added the needed permission and scan works if I call it inside the MainActivity
 **EDIT: **

I have registered the receiver in the MainActivity using this:

```
receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiverWifi,  new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

I'm calling `wifi.startScan()` in `onTouch()` function in my customized view:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    // the coordinate of the touch point
    x=event.getX();
    y=event.getY();

    try {
        touchManager.update(event);

        // single point touch
        if (touchManager.getPressCount() == 1) {


            position.add(touchManager.moveDelta(0)); // to keep the point drawn at the touch location
            info.addToStartPoint(touchManager.moveDelta(0));

            if((touchManager.moveDelta(0).getX()==0 && touchManager.moveDelta(0).getY()== 0))
            {


                PreviousPoint= CurrentPoint;
                CurrentPoint=info.Map(x, y);


                if(CurrentPoint.getX()!=PreviousPoint.getX() && CurrentPoint.getY()!= PreviousPoint.getY())
                {
                    // the point is on the image
                    if(CurrentPoint.getX()!=-1 && CurrentPoint.getY()!= -1)
                    {
                        MainActivity.wifi.startScan();
                        MainActivity.counter++;
                        Log.d("surveyTool","touch: "+MainActivity.counter);
                        MainActivity.location=CurrentPoint;
                        MainActivity.newLocationAvailable=true; 
                        MainActivity.AddNewFingerprin();
                    }

                //  Log.d("surveyTool", " new touch event occurred");
                    // here do the surveying and other stuff    
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            if (touchManager.getPressCount() == 2) {

                Vector2D current = touchManager.getVector(0, 1);
                Vector2D previous = touchManager.getPreviousVector(0, 1);
                float currentDistance = current.getLength();
                float previousDistance = previous.getLength();

                if (previousDistance != 0) {
                    scale *= currentDistance / previousDistance; // for the zoom
                    info.setZoomFactor(scale);

                }// end of != 0
            }// end of if ==2
        }// end of else

        invalidate(); // will cause a redraw
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {

    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

I unregister the receiver in `onPause()` and I register it again in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you unregister your broadcast receiver onPause() of the activity , once your activity is destroyed you will not be able to get the system broadcast for wifi scan results available whenever you call wifi.startScan()

You will need to define a broadcast receiver and register it in the xml to be able to listen to scan results outside the activity.

Make receiver for that:

```
    public class ScanResultsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     //You need to initialise the wifimanager like this 
     private WifiManager wifiManager;
     wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     //Now get Scan Results
     List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();     
    } 
}
```

In your Manifest add

```
<receiver android:name=".wifiReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
//Note: android:name  may differ according to your package structure
```

Now whenever you call wifiManager.startScan() from any activity or anywhere else in the application you will get a system broadcast

Comment: When I did what you suggested I kept getting the message the my application stopped working even though I wasn't running it. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Not sure about that 
Can you tell me what  you added in your  Manifest file ?

Answer (score 1):

May be this is because you are not registering your reciever like this in your source code

```
WifiReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiReceiver();
registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

It will be helpful in answering if you provide some more information, so if this does not works please provide some more information

Comment: I have registered it. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: When are you unregistering the  broadcast receiver .??? If you unregister it in onstop() or ondestroy() of the activity WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION will  not be received after that .
Otherwise your uproach is fine

Comment: I'm unregistering the receiver at onPause() and register it again at onResume()  @SahilBahl

Comment: That is why you are not able to receive the broadcast outside the activity 
Because your broadcast reciever will not work  then.
You will need to define a broadcast receiver and register it in the xml  to be able to listen to scan results outside th application

Comment: @SahilBahl can you please write you comments in an answer so that I can accept it??